# React: Switch Case / Same Component doesn't Unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm implementing a multi-step process in React-native (similar to react).

I have a function that determines which step is displayed :

```
renderStep = step => {

  switch (processStep[step]) {
    case 0:
      return (
        <Product />
      );
      break;
    case 1:
      return (
        <Select data={size} />
      );
      break;
    case 2:
      return (
        <Select data={adresses} />
      );
      break;
    case 3:
      return (
        <RecapOrder />
      );
      break;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

My 2nd et 3rd step are using the same `_stepSelect` component. It uses the same logic, so i'm using the same component.

My issue is : The `Select` component doesn't Unmount between the step `1` and `2` even if the props changes.

So my local State is not reset when changing from step 1 to step 2.

How can i force the Component to be Unmounted.

Comment: A hack I've used is adding a different `key` to the components. React uses keys to determine instances of a component. So if two components have different keys, it should see that as two separate instances.

Comment: Another (better) solution would be to use the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method and handle when new `data` gets passed in the same way you would in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff Well no it doesn't. Otherwise i won't be making this issue :)

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated. I'm not convinced by people's certainty that the same component rendered twice would unmount, in fact, why would it? I would suggest that you don't rely on mounting and instead perform any logic in `componentDidMount` and subsequently in `componentDidUpdate`, instead of forcing react to be less efficient by using keys (or you could try `getDerivedStateFromProps` if using 16.3+).

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Seems like a good idea. I will try.

Comment: @DominicTobias I've never seen anywhere that componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated. componentDidUpdate is triggered with any State Changes (props and state). componentWillReceiveProps is triggered only when new `props` are provided
@ChaseDeAnda feel free to provide a concrete answer so i can try it out

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps, componentWillMount, componentWillUpdate are all going away in React 17. For similar behaviour to cWCP you can use `getDerivedStateFromProps` in future. https://medium.com/@baphemot/whats-new-in-react-16-3-d2c9b7b6193b

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18175
It not going to be deprecated anytime soon.

Comment: @LouisLecocq can you post the code for `<Select>`?

Comment: I don't think using key is a hack. It's just a way to tell React that you want the two Select's to be different components, which it would otherwise not be able to know. It's a much simpler solution than having to worry about resetting state in a lifecycle method, and the one I would prefer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest first trying to add keys to each element being rendering in this function. I have seen issues where React cannot tell the difference between the components being rendered so it skips a few life cycle events and just skips straight to render.

```
<Product key="process-step-product"/>
```

Comment: When running switch on multiple routes with same components with different path, putting keys is necessary for react to be able to differentiate them.